# PHP: Global variable scope

Tags: php

I have a separate file where I include variables with thier set value.
How can I make these variables global?

Ex. I have the value `$myval` in the `values.php` file. In the `index.php` I call a function which needs the `$myval` value.

If I add the `include(values.php);` in the beggining of the index.php file it looses scope inside the function. I will call the same variable in multiple functions in the index.php file.

Comment: You might want to ask yourself why you're using a global variable and if there's a better way to achieve the same thing. Global variables are nearly always a bad idea.

Comment: include has nothing to do with variable scope, is it that hard to investigate?

Comment: If I say that something has a global scope, I expect that when I include the file where the variable was defined as such in my script that it will remain in global scope and can be treated as such.  Yes, after finding out that it doesn't work, it seems like include just redefines the variable for me every time my script runs.  the PHP documentation doesn't talk about this at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inside the function, use the `global` keyword or access the variable from [the `$GLOBALS[]` array](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php):

```
function myfunc() {
  global $myvar;
}
```

Or, for better readability: use `$GLOBALS[]`. This makes it clear that you are accessing something at the global scope.

```
function myfunc() {
  echo $GLOBALS['myvar'];
}
```

Finally though,

Whenever possible, avoid using the global variable to begin with and pass it instead as a parameter to the function:

```
function myfunc($myvar) {
  echo $myvar . " (in a function)";
}

$myvar = "I'm global!";
myfunc($myvar);
// I'm global! (in a function)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use inside your function :

```
global $myval;
```

[PHP - Variable scope](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Answer (score 1):

Using the global keyword in the beginning of your function will bring those variables into scope. So for example

```
$outside_variable = "foo";

function my_function() {
   global $outside_variable;
   echo $outside_variable;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason why you can't pass the variable into your function?

```
myFunction($myVariable)
{
  //DO SOMETHING
}
```

It's a far better idea to pass variables rather than use globals.

Answer (score 0):

Same as if you declared the variable in the same file.

```
function doSomething($arg1, $arg2) {
    global $var1, $var2;
    // do stuff here
}
```