# Variable available to all code?

Tags: php, arrays, class

How can I make variable array available to whole code.

For example, I need to add integers to `$ids[]` inside one **class or function** so I can use it in regular code:

```
class displayClass {
    public function display($field){
        $fieldNum=0;
        $puzzle=$field;
        echo "<form action=\"index.php\" method=\"post\"><table border = \"3\" ><tr>" ;

        for($i=1;$i<=36;$i++){

            if($puzzle[$i]==0){
                echo "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"field".$i."\" maxlength=\"1\" size=\"1\"/></td>";  
                //problem is above... need to sava ids of fields..don't know how
            }  else {

                echo "<td>".$puzzle[$i]."</td>";

            }

            if($i%6==0){
                echo "</tr><tr>";
            }
        }

        echo "</td></table></form>";
    }
}
```

I need to add `$i` to a new existing array which is outside the class.

**EDIT :**

how can i fix this
Strict Standards: Non-static method displayClass::display() should not be called statically in Z:\dev\organization1\project1\htdocs\web\sudoku\index.php on line 35

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8010020/php-global-variable-scope

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you're having to do this then it's a sign that you have design and architecture issues with the codebase you're working with which are beyond the scope of this question.

However to solve your immediate problem, use the [`global`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) keyword:

```
class displayClass {
    public function display($field){

        global $YOUR_VARIABLE_HERE;

        // for example:
        global $ids;

        $fieldNum=0;
        $puzzle=$field;
        echo "<form action=\"index.php\" method=\"post\"><table border = \"3\" ><tr>" ;

        for($i=1;$i<=36;$i++){

            if($puzzle[$i]==0){
                echo "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"field".$i."\" maxlength=\"1\" size=\"1\"/></td>";  
                //problem is above... need to sava ids of fields..don't know how
            }  else {

                echo "<td>".$puzzle[$i]."</td>";

            }

            if($i%6==0){
                echo "</tr><tr>";
            }
        }

        echo "</td></table></form>";
    }
}
```

Assuming of course that `$ids[]` is truly a gobally scoped variable and not defined within an existing function or class.

Comment: In my opinion mixing OOP with the global keyword is not a very nice solution.

Comment: @ZombieHunter - true but clearly the OP has bigger problems than this that are beyond the scope of this question and aren't going to be fixed in an instant.

Comment: Actually, I prefer writing `$GLOBALS['YOUR_VARIABLE_HERE']` in the function instead of declaring it with the `global` statement.

Answer (score 3):

1. class member
2. [global](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) key word
3. singleton pattern
4. static member

### Explanation

**1. Class member**

```
class displayClass
{
    // Members
    // Visible only from inside the class
    private $fieldIds = array();

    // Visible from outside the class by using the instance ($displayClass->publicFieldIds)
    public $publicFieldIds = array();

    // Methods
    public function display($field)
    {
        // ...

        // Add new field ID to member
        $this->fieldIds[] = 1;

        // ...
    }
}
```

**2. `global` key word**

```
global $a, $b;
```

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

**3. Singleton pattern**
See the explanations already available in the web:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Comment: can you explain me better..pls?

Comment: how to acces $fieldIds from outside class?

Comment: @AmmarHadzic: $myClass->myPublicField

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyClass {
    public $a;
    public static $b;

    public function MyMethod {
        // use $a or $b here
    }
}

$myInstance = new MyClass();
$myInstance->$a = 0; // you can access a from outside like this
MyClass::$b = 0; // you can access static b from outside like this
```

Answer (score -1):

The best way would be *proper planning* for your code.

Setting whatever global variables in the class called 'displayClass' is a sure sign of a bad design.
you have to prepare your variables somewhere else and then use either in this class and other code.

and get them in some plain and self-explanatory code like

```
$ids = getWhateverIds();
```

in the global scope.